# How can I sync loved songs on Last.fm and favorite songs on Grooveshark?

Tags: last.fm, grooveshark

The features *loved songs* (Last.fm) and *favorite songs* (Grooveshark) are both for tracking songs that are special to you. Rather than having different collections of such lists of songs it would be nice to be able to sync them.  How can I do this?

I have already found some integration with Last.fm on Grooveshark in [the possibility of scrobbling](http://help.grooveshark.com/customer/portal/articles/2164-last-fm-scrobbling) but I have not found any way to send loved/favorite songs either way. I also know that there are [other players that support import of loved songs](http://www.last.fm/help/faq?category=93#504) and with [Rhythmbox it can be done with scripts](https://askubuntu.com/a/220834/19490).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**sync_songs**](https://github.com/Sleft/sync_songs). It requires Ruby which can be installed via

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1.
```

on Debian-based systems. The simplest way to install sync_songs is via [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/sync_songs) (which can be installed via `sudo apt-get install rubygems1.9.1` on Debian-based systems):

```
sudo gem install sync_songs
```

For details and other ways to install see [the readme](https://github.com/Sleft/sync_songs/blob/master/README.org).

To sync with Last.fm you need an API account as described in [services.org](https://github.com/Sleft/sync_songs/blob/master/services.org). It is free and quite easy to get such an account. Once you have an account you can sync Last.fm loved tracks and Grooveshark favorites via a command of the following form:

```
sync_songs sync --color -vs mary:grooveshark:favorites smith:lastfm:loved
```

Obviously you need to replace `mary` and `smith` with your usernames. You can also add sync to a CSV file to get a local copy (e.g. backup) of your favorites and loved tracks:

```
sync_songs sync --color -vs mary:grooveshark:favorites smith:lastfm:loved file_path:csv:library
```

You need to replace `file_path` with a path to an existing empty file.

Comment: This project appears to be defunct.